# Float' object has no attribute

Tags: python, formatting

I just started to learn python. I am getting the following error.

```
a=15/737

print("String formating with value{r.1.4f}".format(r=a))
```

---

AttributeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
---- > 1  print ( "string formating with value {r.1.4f}" . format ( r = a ) )

AttributeError : 'float' object has no attribute '1

Can anyone tell me what is worng here?

Comment: You need to use colon `:` instead of `.` i.e. `{r:1.4f}`

Answer (score 2):

It's a just syntax error:

Put a colon (:) behind r instead of a point(.) and it will work.